# How do we define morphisms on a functor?

Tags: category-theory

Let $F:C\to Set$ be a functor. Let $\int F$ represent the category of elements. We shall define a functor $\int(-):Set^C\to Cat/C$ where $\int(-)(F):=\int F$. Now let $G,H:C\to Set$ be  functors and $\alpha:G\Rightarrow H$ be a natural transformation. My question is how do we define $\int(-)(\alpha)$?

Comment: $\alpha$ is a family of maps (in $\mathrm{Set}$). You can apply $\int (-)$ to a functor $C\to \mathrm{Set}$. In short *does not compute*.

Comment: Then how do you define my desired functor?

Answer (score 3):

As usual in category theory, there's only really one definition that makes sense, and that definition is the one you want.

In particular, given a natural transformation $\alpha : F \to G$, you need to define a functor
$$\textstyle \int \alpha : \int F \to \int G$$
Given an object $(C,x)$ of $\int F$, note that $(C, \alpha_C(x))$ is an object of $\int G$, so this suggests defining $(\int \alpha)(C,x) = \alpha_C(x)$ as the action of $\int \alpha$ on objects.

See if you can figure out how to define $\int \alpha$ on morphisms.

Comment: I would say the usual situation in category theory is that there's *seemingly* multiple definitions that make sense but that there are usually coherence conditions that make them all the same (or at least the same up to isomorphism). It's fairly common for a sketch of a definition to include the phrase "with the obvious coherence conditions" which usually means roughly that all the different ways you could make a natural transformation between two given functors using the data of the definition are the same.